# Validate connection to the stage deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

The web app is running fine in Prod. There was no stage previously. So I asked the infra team to create a stage slot, so that I can deploy the application to stage then to the Prod (just following the best Azure practice).

However, when I'm creating a profile from the Visual Studio using Publish profile (to publish in stage), in "connection" tab, I'm providing all the details from the Azure portal ( stage details) and when I clicked on "Validate connection":

```
   its throughout a error "Could not connect to remote computer".
```

The question is why this error is coming? Does infra team given something wrong? If Infra team is configuring something wrong, then why Azure portal can't stop or validate during infrastructure configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to turn off SCM? Set WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = false as an application setting. After selecting save, download the publishing profile again for your deployment slot (not the publishing profile for the main app).